# Meaning of indicator variable in this problem

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

Suppose I have 52 cards, and I want to find the expected number of cards before I draw an ace. As usual, I solve the problem using indicator variables. Letting $X_j$ be the indicator variable that the $j^{\text{th}}$ card is a non-ace drawn before the first ace, and $1\leq j\leq 48$ (since there are 48 non-aces), we have

$$E(X) = E(X_1 + ... + X_{48})$$
$$= E(X_1)+...+E(X_{48})\quad\text{(linearity)}$$
$$=48E(X_1)\quad\text{(symmetry)}$$
$$=\frac{48}{5}.$$

My confusion is regarding the last step and the definition of $X_j$. Why is it defined as such? Why do we only use a sample of the 1st non-ace and the 4 other aces, ignoring the other non-aces? Thank you!

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Surely $X_j$ as you defined it, depends on $j$.  The probability that the first card is a non-ace followed by an ace is $\frac {48}{52}\times \frac 4{51}$.  That the second is a non-ace followed by the first ace is $\frac {48}{52}\times \frac {47}{51}\times \frac 4{50}$.  Not the same.

Comment: @lulu hmm then where does the 1/5 come from?

Comment: Well, not from anything I can see here.  you can get the expectation explicitly from the probabilities, though it is a messy sum.  But maybe you had something else in mind.,.hard to tell from what you wrote.

Comment: The way I always see problems like this:  imagine that there is a Joker and arrange the $53$ cards in a circle.  Now there are five gaps between the Joker+Aces.  Now symmetry tells us that the gaps should all have the same expected length, and use the Joker to mark where the "deal" starts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expected number of cards you should turn before finding an ace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138853/expected-number-of-cards-you-should-turn-before-finding-an-ace)