# Expected value of tries to draw a red-colored marble, no marbles returned to the jar

Tags: statistics

What is the expected value of the number of tries it'll take to draw $1$ red-colored marble from a jar of $R$ red marbles and $N-R$ non-red marbles (*i.e.* $N$ total marbles)? The drawn marbles are not returned to the jar.

I've translated my actual problem to the marbles scenario because I thought I'd find my answer this way, but it seems searching for a statistics question that exactly matches your scenario is kind of hard. Sorry if this is a duplicate.

I'm trying to calculate something about UUIDs, so in my case $R \approx 31\times10^9$ and $N = 16^{32}$. And I just need to know the order of magnitude of the answer, which I can deduce from a general formula.

Comment: the usual argument:  suppose you add one special marble.  Then arrange all the $N+1$ marbles in a circle uniformly at random.  By symmetry the expected gaps between the $R+1$ (red + special) marbles are all the same.  Now remove the special one to get the linear ordering associated with a draw.

Comment: The answer is $\frac{N-R}{R+1}$. This is because,  for each of the $N-R$ non-red marbles, the probability that it is drawn before the first red marble is $\frac1{R+1}$. For the case $N=52,\ R=4$ see [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138853/expected-number-of-cards-you-should-turn-before-finding-an-ace/2265291#2265291) to the question [Expected number of cards you should turn before finding an ace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138853/expected-number-of-cards-you-should-turn-before-finding-an-ace).

Comment: @bof Ah, thank you! I can see the cards are the same setup. Okay, so for my application it's really just $\frac{N}{R}$.

Comment: @bof - your $\frac{N-R}{R+1}$ is expected non-reds *before* the first red, and would be $\frac{N+1}{R+1}$ if you included the first red.  lulu's argument would give the same result

Comment: @Henry Right you are, I missed that. Thanks for the correction.