# Using Symmetry in calculating expectations

Tags: probability, combinatorics, soft-question, terminology, symmetry

> Shuffle an ordinary deck of 52 playing cards containing four aces.
> Then turn up the cards from the top until the first ace appears. On
> the average how many cards are required to be turned before producing
> the first ace?

The question is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2101157/240768) using symmetry. I have seen other such [questions](https://hmmt-archive.s3.amazonaws.com/tournaments/2007/feb/comb/solutions.pdf).

Is there a name for this method? Specifically, is there a name for the type of symmetry being used.

Note: I don't want a solution. There are many solutions already available. I am asking for a name for the symmetry used.

Comment: (no known name ; a generic name for this kind of questions is "runs"). A remark : the accepted answer is a little "handwaving" : happily there is the comment by Roy !

Answer (score 1):

*Expectation* is about averages, so one way to understand this problem is to imagine the $52$ cards make $52$ "cuts" on a $0-1$ line, so are  evenly placed at $1/53, 2/53, ...k/53,...52/53$

Likewise, the aces would make "cuts" to be evenly placed at $1/5,2/5/...5/5$

I can't say **what type** of symmetry this is, it is just symmetry of evenly placed elements **on an average**

Then the first ace will be found at the point  so that $1/5 = k/53 \Rightarrow k = 53/5 = 10.6$

Another more formal  way to get the same result is to use  indicator random variables. Consider the $4$ aces together in conjunction with one non-ace, and define an indicator variable $X_i$ for the  non-ace $i$  to have $Pr=1$ if it is in front of all the aces, $0$ otherwise

so $P(X_i) = \frac15$, since the non-ace is equally likely to be at any of the $5$ positions

Now the expectation of an indicator variable is just the probability of the event it indicates, thus

$\mathbb{E}[X_i] = P(X_i) = \frac15$

and by linearity of expectation, which operates even when the random variables are not independent,

$\mathbb{E}[X] = \Sigma{ \mathbb{E}[X_i]} = \frac{48}5 = 9.6$

and the first ace is expected to be at position $9.6+1 =10.6$

**PS**

If "*how many cards are required to be turned before producing the first ace*" is interpreted to exclude the first ace, the answer will be one less, $9.6$