# Expected number of cards drawn before the first ace

Tags: probability, induction, expected-value

I'm attempting to solve this problem [Expected number of cards you should turn before finding an ace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138853/expected-number-of-cards-you-should-turn-before-finding-an-ace) using the law of total expectation and recursion, but my solution approach seems really convoluted, and I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious

I start with a top-down approach. Let $A$ denote the event of drawing the first ace.
Let $M$ denote the number of cards we're drawing from, $N$ the number of draws to get the first ace. Then the law of total expectation gives us the following recurrence relationship:
$$
E[N|M=d] = \frac{d-4}{d}\big(1+E[N|M=d-1]\big) + \frac{4}{d}(1)
$$

The base case is
$$
E[N|M=4] = 1
$$
So we can write a out a few more cases
$$
E[N|M=5] = \frac{1}{5}\big(1+E[N|M=4]\big) + \frac{4}{5}
= 1.2 \\ 
E[N|M=6] = \frac{2}{6}(1+1.2) + \frac{4}{6} = 1.4 \\
E[N|M=7] = \frac{3}{7}(1+1.4) + \frac{4}{7} = 1.6 \\
$$
So it appears each time we increment $M$, the expectation increases by 0.2, where we can then deduce the following non-recurrent formula:
\begin{align}
E[N|M=d] = 1+0.2*(d-4)
\end{align}

We can prove that this formula holds for all $4 \leq k \leq 52$ by induction and assume this formula holds for $M=k$:
$$
E[N|M=k] = 1+0.2(k-4) 
$$
and use this to make the claim that this holds for $M=k+1$
$$
E[N|M=k+1] = 1+0.2(k-3)
$$

To prove this, we can use the recurrence relationship we derived earlier along with $E[N|M=k] = 1+0.2(k-4) $
\begin{align}
    E[N|M=k+1] = (1+E[N|M=k])\frac{k-3}{k+1} + \frac{4}{k+1} 
    \\
    = (1+1+0.2(k-4))\frac{k-3}{k+1} + \frac{4}{k+1} \\
    = (2-0.8 + 0.2k))\frac{k-3}{k+1} + \frac{4}{k+1} \\
    = (1.2 + 0.2k)\frac{k-3}{k+1} + \frac{4}{k+1} \\
    = \frac{(1.2k + 0.2k^2 - 3.6 - 0.6k)}{k+1} + \frac{4}{k+1} \\
    = \frac{(0.6k + 0.2k^2 +0.4)}{k+1} \\
    = \frac{0.2(3k + k^2 +2)}{k+1} \\
    = 0.2(k+2) \\
    = 1+ 0.2*(k-3)\\
\end{align}
We have shown that this formula holds through proof by induction.

The other solutions that were posted are much shorter. Were there any tricks that I missed in my approach that could have shortened this?

Comment: There is, of course, a reason why people prefer alternate methods of solution.

Comment: @lulu Right, but I was wondering if I did something unnecessary with my approach to arrive at the conclusion, but it doesn't seem I did. I feel like every step I did for my approach was necessary.

Comment: It looks pretty efficient to me...I don't think you are missing any obvious tricks.

Comment: the number of cards you draw before there is an ace is a geometric RV. You should look up what that means if you don't know, it will simplify your answer

Comment: @BinyaminR  Well, it would be geometric if you were drawing with replacement, but the OP is clearly working without replacement.

Comment: @BinyaminR Yes, and I think that approach is not more clever, but I don't think knowing that it's a geometric RV simplifies this particular approach that I used that uses law of total expectation?

Comment: Should say:  There's nothing wrong with recursive methods.  They come up all the time. Implementing this one gives the answer as quickly as you can type it.  Lots of times there are no elegant methods available, and recursions are all you get.

Comment: @lulu Oh wait you're right. I was thinking of another approach given by Andre in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245354/expected-value-of-sums

Comment: So there are $4$ aces in a deck of $M$ cards for every $M = 4, 5, ... , 52$?

Comment: @jeremy909 Yes, that's technically the way I defined $M$ in this case. So if $M=4$, they are all aces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make things a little more compact, I'll write $$e_d=E[N|M=d]$$  Then your recurrence relation is $$e_d=1+\frac{d-4}de_{d-1}$$ or $$de_d = d +(d-4)e_{d-1}\tag1$$ and we know $e_4=1$.  You have guessed the formula $$e_d=1+.2(d-4)\tag2$$  $(2)$ is clearly correct when $d=4$.  To prove it correct for $d\ge4$, all you need to do is substitute $(2)$ in both sides of $(1)$ and check that the statement is true.

Comment: Good point. Is this still formally "proof by induction" or is some other kind of proof? The way I learned proof by induction always involves assuming the deduced formula holds for some $k$, and use this to show that it holds for $k+1$.

Comment: @Iamanon It's a general fact about recurrence relations.  To establish the general fact, you use induction.  After that, you don't need induction any more. But, yes at bottom is a proof by induction.